# TSQL - Same query, dfferent result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-view

I have a view that unions a single row of hardcoded values (zero's and blanks) with the results of a query. The view definition contains a select statement along the lines of the below.

```
    SELECT 
      '0' AS Col1,
      ''  AS Col2,
      ''  AS Col3,
      '0' AS Col4
    UNION
    SELECT
      Val1 AS Col1,
      Val2 AS Col2,
      Val3 AS Col3,
      Val4 AS Col4
    FROM MyTable
```

When I execute the statement interactively I get the following result

```
    Col1    Col2     Col3     Col4
    ------------------------------
    0      'blank'  'blank'   0
    Val1    Val2     Val3     Val4
```

However when I select from the view I get

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4
    ------------------------------
    0       0      'blank'   0
    Val1    Val2    Val3     Val4
```

Why would the hardcoded blank value for Col2 start returning a zero?

If I create a new view using the same definition I get the expected result (i.e. the same result I get when running interactively) with a 'blank' for Col2.

It only appears to be the hardcoded values that are affected.

Comment: it is most likely that `Table2.Val2` is a numeric column. The DB engine implicitly converts it either to string or number depending on the sort order of the result. To fix it use the explicit `CAST(Val2 as VARCHAR(20))` in your UNION statement

Comment: probably value fields are numeric that's why you get a mixed output but sql should throw a type mismatch

Comment: Thank you cha, it was indeed a numeric value.